# Create a switch from a given macro

Tags: macros

I would like to create the equivalent of what `\bfseries` is for `\textbf`, relative to the command `\shadowtext`, which is defined as:

```
\newcommand\shadowtext[1]%
{%
   \begingroup%
   \settowidth{\st@temp@width}{#1}%
   \settoheight{\st@temp@height}{#1}%
   \setlength{\st@pic@width}{\st@temp@width}%
   \setlength{\st@pic@height}{\st@temp@height}%
   \addtolength{\st@pic@width}{\st@shadowoffsetx}%
   \addtolength{\st@pic@height}{\st@shadowoffsety}%
   %
   \edef\num@tw{\strip@pt\st@temp@width}%
   \edef\num@th{\strip@pt\st@temp@height}%
   \edef\num@pw{\strip@pt\st@pic@width}%
   \edef\num@ph{\strip@pt\st@pic@height}%
   \edef\num@offsetx{\strip@pt\st@shadowoffsetx}%
   \edef\num@offsety{\strip@pt\st@shadowoffsety}%
   \raisebox{-\st@shadowoffsety}{
   \begin{picture}(\num@pw,\num@ph)(0,0)
        \put(\num@offsetx,0){\makebox(\num@tw,\num@th)[tl]{\color{\st@shadowcolor}\def\color##1{}\ignorespaces #1}}
        \put(0,\num@offsety){\makebox(\num@tw,\num@th)[tl]{\ignorespaces #1}}
    \end{picture}}%
    \endgroup%
    \ignorespaces%
}
```

My first naive try was to make the argument optional, but that of course didn't work out :).

So, how do i turn `\shadowtext` into a switch like `\bfseries`?

Comment: Here is the definition: `\long macro:->\not@math@alphabet \bfseries \mathbf \fontseries \bfdefault \selectfont`

Comment: `\bfseries` is just an instruction telling TeX “from now on, typeset in boldface”; there is no look up in advance of the material to be typeset in boldface. Your `\shadowtext` macro *needs* to know what it must operate on.

Comment: This is often referred to as a switch, since it doesn't require turns something on from that point forward.

Comment: @egreg so there is no way of saying: "from now on add a shadow to all the text"?

Comment: @Jansen no way in general no. Note that `\textbf` is defined in terms of `\bfseries` , not the other way round.

Comment: @Jansen You need a special font, for that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle; egreg Oh, I see now. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Just as an example, if you want to create a new font command, to switch to Zapf Chancery, for example, you could say `\DeclareRobustCommand{\zapfstyle}{%
 \fontencoding{T1}%
 \fontseries{mb}%
 \fontshape{it}%
 \fontfamily{pzc}%
 \selectfont}` and *then* you would define the `\text...` form in terms of that switch e.g. `\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textzf}{\zapfstyle}`. But this works just because it is just doing font switching - there's nothing fancier involved. Defining commands to cope with non-standard shapes, series etc. gets more complex, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what happens if the content is other than text, but I made sure to make it work with embedded `\par`s.  However, considering that the standard macro form `\shadowtext{}` cannot line break, this offers a notable improvement.

Use `\beginshadowtext` and `\endshadowtext` like environment delimiters.

Note: the `\kern`s are needed because the underlying `\shadowtext` macro is a bit funky.  You will note from the first line of output that the macro form does not align with the paragraph indent.  Also on the same line of text, a space had to be manually added at the end of the macro-form invocation, which should not be the case.  So the `\kern`s in my environment are to compensate for those deficiencies.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{shadowtext}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\long\def\beginshadowtext#1\endshadowtext{\shadowtexthelper#1 \relax\relax\kern0.666ex}
\long\def\shadowtexthelper#1 #2\relax{%
  \isnextbyte[q]{\par}{#1}%
  \if T\theresult\par\gobbleshadowtext#1\relax\relax\else%
    \shadowtext{#1}\ \kern-.666ex\fi%
  \ifx\relax#2\else\shadowtexthelper#2\relax\fi%
  }
\long\def\gobbleshadowtext#1#2\relax{%
  \isnextbyte[q]{\par}{#2}%
  \if T\theresult\par\gobbleshadowtext#2\relax\relax\else%
    \leavevmode\kern-0.666ex\shadowtext{#2}\ \kern-.666ex\fi%
}
\parskip 1em
\begin{document}
\shadowtext{This is a test}\ xyz

Start now!\beginshadowtext
This is a test this is a test this is a test. this is a test
this is a test this is a test. this is a test this is a test this is a test.
This is a test this is a test this is a test. this is a test
this is a test this is a test. this is a test this is a test this is a test.

this is a test this is a test this is a test. this is a test
this is a test. this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test.
\par\par\par
The end.\endshadowtext
Back to normal.
\end{document}
```

[image]